Adjust Visual limits of colorbar legend in ggplot2 (R)
I want to represent the evolution of a variable (Observation) in the time. I want to color each point according to the value using the color code
Everything works, no issue with the code. But, aesthetically, the render of the colorbar lagend is not good. I want to limit the colorbar legend at a specific interval to better see the differences between colors for small values. I don't want to restrict the color mapping, just the appearance of the colorbar.
My code is :
# Definitions of color scale
colors <- c("black", "grey", "darkred", "red", "tomato", "white", "white",
            "lightgreen", "green", "darkgreen", "darkolivegreen", 
            "cyan", "blue", "darkblue", "midnightblue", "purple", 
            "magenta", "darkmagenta", "yellow", "gold4")
values <- c(-10, -5, -3, -1.5, -0.001, 0, 0.001, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 200, 500, 1000)

# Plot
ggplot(notes2023, aes(x = Date, y = Observations)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Observations), size = 1) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = colors, values = scales::rescale(values), limits = c(-10, 1000),
                        oob = scales::squish, name = 'Indice', 
                        guide = guide_colorbar(direction = "vertical", barwidth = 1, barheight = 10, limits = c(-10, 100), title.position = "top")) +
  geom_smooth(color = "black", span = 0.2, size = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = pseudolog10_trans, breaks = c(-5, 0, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 1000)) +
  labs(title = "Observations journalières", subtitle = "2023", x = "Date", y = "Observation") +
  theme_clean(base_size = 5) +
  theme(legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.text = element_text(size = 6))

The plot is this :


This is not an answer to your question, but a suggestion for an alternative approach to limiting the colourbar.
Have you considered using a scale transformation to get a more even spread of colours?
library(ggplot2)

colors <- c("black", "grey", "darkred", "red", "tomato", "white", "white",
            "lightgreen", "green", "darkgreen", "darkolivegreen", 
            "cyan", "blue", "darkblue", "midnightblue", "purple", 
            "magenta", "darkmagenta", "yellow", "gold4")
values <- c(-10, -5, -3, -1.5, -0.001, 0, 0.001, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 200, 500, 1000)

df <- data.frame(x = seq(-10, 1000, length.out = 100))

trans <- scales::pseudo_log_trans()

ggplot(df, aes(x, x, colour = x)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(
    colours = colors, values = scales::rescale(trans$transform(values)),
    breaks = c(-10, 0, 10, 100, 1000),
    limits = c(-10, 1000),
    transform = trans
  )


Created on 2024-06-04 with reprex v2.1.0
